# RoR - how to make an .each loop on views pass a variable to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to add votes to comments on my blog application. But i cant seem to be able to send the variable within the below loop to the controller:

```
<% @comments.each do |c| %>
   <h1><%= c.title %></h1>
   <p><%= c.content %></p>
   <p><%= c.user.username %></p>

   <% if current_user.id == c.user_id %>
    <%= link_to "Edit",  edit_comment_path(@post, c)%>
    <%= link_to "Delete", delete_comment_path(@post, c), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }%>
   <% end %>
   <% if current_user.id != c.user_id %>
      <p>Review this comment</p>

      <%= link_to like_path(c), method: :put do %>
        Upvote
        <%= c.upvote %>
      <% end %>

      <%= link_to dislike_path(c), method: :put do %>
        Downvote
        <%= c.downvote %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

controller:

```
...
def upvote

    object_comment = Comment.find(@comment.id)
    object_comment.increment!(:upvote)
    redirect_to show_path(@post)

  end

  def downvote
    object_comment = Comment.find(@comment.id)
    object_comment.increment!(:downvote)
    redirect_to show_path(@post)
  end
....
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 .... 
  #Comments
  post    '/post/:post_id',                                  to: 'comment#create',    as: 'new_comments'
  get     '/post/:post_id/:comment_id/edit',                 to: 'comment#edit',      as: 'edit_comment'
  put     '/post/:post_id/comment/:comment_id',              to: 'comment#update',    as: 'update_comment'
  delete  '/post/:id/:comment_id/',                          to: 'comment#destroy',   as: 'delete_comment'
  put     'like',                       to: "comment#upvote",    as: 'like'
  put     'dislike',                                         to: "comment#downvote",  as: 'dislike'


end
```

I would like to receive the 'c' stated on the each loop as a variable on the upvote and downvote methods to replace the @comment within object_comment = Comment.find(@comment.id), in order to increment the votes. is this possible?

As it is right i obviously receive the following error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: I guess you should add `:id` parameter to your `like` and `dislike` paths.

Comment: As the above, id go with something like: `put '/post/:post_id/comment/:comment_id/upvote'` This might change the helper, but thats a simple update.

Comment: You should have a look at [*nested resources*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) and [*member routes*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: @DickieBoy I'd avoid deep nesting of resources and instead use `put '/comment/:id/upvote'`

Comment: @JohanWentholt I wouldn't call two layers "deep nesting", 2 is fine. 3 starts to get a little off, 4 shouldn't happen,

Comment: @DickieBoy It depends on your definition of *deep*. However the Ruby guide about nested resources (linked by Pavan) says the following: *"Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep."*

Comment: @JohanWentholt yeah looks like we have an off by one error, what I call 2 you call 1. Deep for me is 3(2)+ starts to get frustrating getting all the right things in the right place. Although, it has its places. Especially when permissions for the base objects start to get involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `*_path` methods do not know what to do with that single argument. (If you want to pass an object to your links, you might want to research RESTful routing. However, to solve it with your current routes, I suggest

```
<%= link_to "Downvote #{c.downvote}" dislike_path(id: c.id) %>
```

It should then be possible to access this `id` attribute in the controller via `params`.

```
def dislike
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

---

A couple of other things to think about:

It's very unusual to perform a `put` action on clicking a link. You might want to consider doing this as a `get` action instead.

Does the `downvote` method return something which is different for each comment? If not, it's standard practise to include it in the controller's helper.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply! doing this how should i then use it on my controller? I see what you mean about the 'get' method, i'll look into it. i thought about 'put' as a means to update the upvote and downvote parameters from each comment.

Comment: @JoãoMateus Sorry, I missed that detail. I've updated my question.

Comment: Thanks, @AJFaraday, i made it work with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can get id in parameters, please check below methods

```
def upvote

    object_comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    object_comment.increment!(:upvote)
    redirect_to show_path(@post)

  end

  def downvote
    object_comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    object_comment.increment!(:downvote)
    redirect_to show_path(@post)
  end
....
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing it wrong. You'll need to save the user's action on the comment with a model `CommentVote` for example that belongs to `user` and `comment`.

Then you'll need to do something like:

```
class CommentVote
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :user
  enum type: [:upvote, :downvote]

  def self.vote(type:, comment_id:, user_id:)
    comment_vote = CommentVote.where(comment_id: comment_id, user_id: user_id).first_or_initialize
    comment_vote.type = type
    comment_vote.save
  end
end
```

And then do a `after_save :update_counts` in the `CommentVote` model:

```
def update_counts
  self.comment.upvote = self.comment.comment_votes.upvote.count
  self.comment.downvote = self.comment.comment_votes.downvote.count
  self.comment.save
end
```

and you'll call it like: `CommentVote.vote(type: :upvote, comment_id: 1, user_id: 1)`

Comment: The question was about how to pass this variable to the controller, to be used while clicking on a link. This is an answer about how the model is structured.

Comment: @AJFaraday 100%; but I saw that you had already answered it, so I thought of helping him in model / database structuring :-)